# opencart json success not working

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I'm using `Opencart v1.5.6`. I've changed the product `review` to `discus`. The problem is that the success notification doesn't show, but the error notification does.

Controller:

```
    public function writediscus() {
    $this->language->load('product/product');
    $this->load->model('catalog/discus');
    $json = array();
    if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name2']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name2']) > 25)) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text2']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text2']) > 1000)) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
        }
        if (empty($this->session->data['captcha2']) || ($this->session->data['captcha2'] != $this->request->post['captcha2'])) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
        }
        else {
            $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        }
        if (!isset($json['error'])) {
            $this->model_catalog_discus->addDiscus($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);
            $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        }
    }
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Code:

```
    <div id="tab-discus" class="tab-content">
    <div id="discus"></div>
    <h2 id="discus-title">
        <?php echo $text_write_vendor; ?>
    </h2>
    <?php if($this->customer->isLogged() ) { ?>
    <b><?php echo $entry_name; ?></b><br />
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <b><?php echo $entry_discus; ?></b>
    <textarea name="text2" cols="40" rows="8" style="width: 98%;"></textarea>
    <span style="font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $text_note; ?></span><br />
    <br />
    <b><?php echo $entry_captcha; ?></b><br /> <br />
    <img src="index.php?route=product/product/captcha2" alt="" id="captcha2" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="captcha2" value="" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a id="button-discus" class="button">
                <?php echo $button_continue; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } else {?>
    <?php echo $text_ask_vendor; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $('#discus .pagination a').live('click', function() {
        $('#discus').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#discus').load(this.href);
        $('#discus').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('#discus').load('index.php?route=product/product/discus&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>');
    $('#button-discus').bind('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=product/product/writediscus&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'name2=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'name2\']').val()) + '&text2=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'text2\']').val()) + '&captcha2=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'captcha2\']').val()),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.success, .warning').remove();
                $('#button-discus').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#discus-title').after('<div class="attention"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-discus').attr('disabled', false);
                $('.attention').remove();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data['error']) {
                    $('#discus-title').after('<div class="warning">' + data['error'] + '</div>');
                }

                if (data['success']) {
                    $('#discus-title').after('<div class="success">' + data['success'] + '</div>');
                    $('input[name=\'name2\']').val('');
                    $('textarea[name=\'text2\']').val('');
                    $('input[name=\'captcha2\']').val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    //-->
</script>
```

The problem is that the JSON returning `success` is not working while the `error` does. Can someone suggest something.

Comment: do `console.info()` in your JS to see what response you are getting

Comment: can u please do console.log(data) in success,what are you getting in response.

Comment: check your language file that text_success key available or not.

Comment: @DhavalPanchal I put either console.info() and console.log(data) under the if (data['success']) { (did I put the console tag in the right place?) and did the false test and the result is both error and success notification shown. BUT when I did the TRUE test, nothing shows up and the database entered as usual.

Comment: are you debug the $this->model_catalog_discus->addDiscus($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post); method.